# How to set Select2 value using initSelection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using jQuery Select2 for dropdown lists. The data is loading via AJAX call using in JSON format.

Here is my script:

```
$("#sub_lessons").select2({ 
     maximumSelectionSize: 1,
     placeholder: "Select Sublessons",
     allowClear: true,
     multiple:true,
        ajax: {
          url: "getData.action?lid="+lessonid,   
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (term, page) {
            return {
              q: term
            };
          },
          results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data };

          }
        } 
    });
```

My html snippet:

```
<input type="hidden" id="sub_lessons" style="width:300px"/>
```

When we clicking on the select2 box the data is loading perfectly,
but I have the function like setValue() when button is clicked.

```
<input type="button" onclick="setValue(1)"/>
```

And my function is:

```
function setValue(no)
{
 $('#sub_lessons').select2('val',no);
}
```

But the value is not being set. I searched in some sites and suggested to use initselection.I used initselection,but it does not work.please help me how to set value to select2 when button is pressed.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did your Json is in id and text format ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#sub_lessons').select2('val','no');
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this; work for me. You should add this to initSelection select2:

```
        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
        var id = $(element).val();
        $.ajax("url/" + id, {
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            var newOption = new Option(data.title, data.id, true, true);
            $('#sub_lessons').append(newOption).trigger('change');
            callback({"text": data.title, "id": data.id});
        });
    },
```

Comment: how this initSelection will be called ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? this initSellection call when we want to set a value of select input. In select input data load with ajax search on  typing some words.@AwaisUsmani